# Подстановка значения в переменную при условии в Python

Tags: javascript, python

В Javascript(EcmaScript) возможно такое выражение:

```
let a = 10;
let b = 20;
let result = (a === b) ? 'lala' : 'qweqwe';
```

Как подобное сделать в Python(3), если, конечно, это возможно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Аналог тернарного оператора в Python:

```
res = "Yup" if a==b else "Nope"
```

Либо через кортеж:

```
res = ("no","yes")[a==b]
```